# Press enter instead of mouse click (Angular modal- Plunker attached)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

http://plnkr.co/edit/v3NWuyIP2M9tcRG1qT7j?p=preview

As per the plunker, if i click on 'Open Me' button, a modal appears and asks user to press input. Once done, the user has to click on ok with the mouse in order to proceed further.

Can someone let me know how to proceed further just by pressing the enter from the keyboard rather than using the mouse. Is there any way ?

```
<div class="modal-body">
        Check User ID: <input type="text" ng-model="data.User_ID">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your input add

```
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && ok()"
```

This will call the ok method when enter is hit